# Axios fetch in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need some assistent in using Axios in my react app. I use it in combination with geolocation to get the users location and use it in the api call with Axios.

My code is:

```
componentDidMount() {
 if (navigator.geolocation){

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var th = this;
    this.serverRequest =
      axios.get(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/`+latitude+`,`+longitude+`?units=auto`)
        .then(result => {
          th.setState({
            daily: result.data.daily.data,
            loading: false,
            error: null
          });
        })
      .catch(err => {
        // Something went wrong. Save the error in state and re-render.
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          error: err
        });
      });
  };
  function error() {
    console.log( 'geolocation error' )
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
 }
}
```

but i end up with the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'serverRequest' of undefined`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `success` is called as a callback, its `this` value won't be right - in your case it's `undefined`. You can fix this by using `bind` on your callback function:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success.bind(this), error);
```

Comment: You've made my day. Thanks!